# R not recognizing analyze() function in psycho package?

Tags: r

I'm trying to use the Psycho package to analyze a model. I've tried installing Psycho through CRAN as well as install_github and the installation worked. The package is loaded but the analyze function is not being recognized. I've tried psycho::analyze which also does not work. Following this [question](https://github.com/neuropsychology/psycho.R/issues/87) I also installed and loaded statnet.common. Any suggestions?

```
Error in analyze(m2, CI = 95) : could not find function "analyze"
```

Comment: Is this from the package `psycho`.  I couldn't find that function [here](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/psycho/psycho.pdf)

Comment: ooh interesting...I'm following this tutorial maybe it's not updated though: https://neuropsychology.github.io/psycho.R/2018/05/10/interpret_mixed_models.html

Comment: If it is from `github`, then you need to install that updated package and not from `CRAN`

Comment: What version of the package are you using? Is it 0.5? Did you see the message at startup that said "Many functions of the psycho package have been (improved and) moved to other packages of the new 'easystats' collection (https://github.com/easystats). If you don't find where a function is gone, please open an issue at: https://github.com/easystats/easystats/issues". I think that function has been replaced by https://github.com/easystats/report

Comment: It is version .5 and I didn't see that message. Thanks for those links I'll look into that

Answer (score 1):

For any future person that comes across this, I was also having problems with the analyze() function. One can use the following solution that worked for me:

```
> install.packages("remotes")
> remotes::install_github("easystats/report")
> library("report")
> report(m2) # use this instead of analyze()
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue while trying to follow this tutorial: https://neuropsychology.github.io/psycho.R//2018/05/01/repeated_measure_anovas.html
(and I wish it was updated, unfortunately it still refers to outdated functions).

Potential solutions (alternative library) are discussed on this page: https://github.com/easystats/easystats/issues/58
Unfortunately, I have not managed to get these to work, but other people commented that the solutions worked for them.